# Dependency error during storefront setup for default application

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am getting the following error while running the server (ng serve) while setting up the spartacus storefront.

```
@spartacus/core/spartacus-core"' has no exported member 'CartService'. Did you mean 'AuthService'?
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue solved by updating the dependencies and running `npm audit fix` on the application.